# jquery keep showing div after refresh if php validation fails

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select box that shows and hides form elements using jquery.  The  hide and show works.  But when I submit the form, if there's PHP validation errors, the form that's showing is hidden after refresh.   I've searched and search but can't find a solution that fits with my code.  If someone could show me how to show the form submitted if validation errors exist that would be great.  See code below.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
</script>


<form action="" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post" name="form">
<select id="colorselector">
 <option selected></option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>

<div id="1" class="colors" style="display:none">
 <input type="text" name="1">
 <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> 
</div
><div id="2" class="colors" style="display:none">
 <input type="text" name="1">
 <input type="text" name="2">
 <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</div></form>
```

Comment: You can check the post value, and echo a `<script>` to shows that `<div>`. for example - `if(isset($_POST['colorselector'])){ echo "<script>$(function() { $('#.$_POST['colorselector']."').show();});</script>";}`

Comment: Or you could dynamically evoke a change of the <select>, for example - `if(isset($_POST['colorselector'])){ echo "<script>$(function() { $('#colorselector').val($_POST['colorselector']); });</script>";}`. By changing the value of the `<select>`, it will trigger your `$('#colorselector').change(function(){...}`

Comment: You can save the value of the colorselector in a cookie or localStorage. Then when the page is loaded, get the cookie and show the appropriate DIV.

Comment: Or you can give a name to the color selector, so its value will be submitted with the form. Then the PHP code can hide and show the appropriate DIVs by default based on `$_POST['colorselector']`.

Comment: Or you could use a ternary to echo your `style="display:none"` in your `<div>`s, for example - `<?php echo (if(isset($_POST['colorselector'])) && $_POST['colorselector'] == 1) ?  '' : 'style="display:none"'`.

Comment: Sean, I like your last code sample but there's errors in it and I'm not familiar enough to fix it.

Comment: And your first code but it doesn't like - #.$_POST['colorselector']."

Comment: The 1st is missing a `"` before `$_POST['colorselector']`. Should be `...$('#."$_POST['colorselector']."').show();...`. The last is missing the `; ?>`, and should be without the `if` -> `<?php echo (isset($_POST['colorselector']) && $_POST['colorselector'] == 1) ? '' : 'style="display:none"''; ?>`

Comment: Thanks.... I'm not getting errors from your code.  I've used both the 1st and last code block but doesn't do anything.  I added above the jquery.... added under the <form> and added it after the select but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok added it to each div.... and getting something.  But the form doesn't display when an option is selected.   The form displays after refresh but disappears when an option is selected.